# Form to always show when not maximised?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, z-order

I am developing a C# form that is a countdown Timer.  When the form is maximised it fills the whole screen fine.  However when the maximise button is clicked i have configured it to be smaller.  However is there a way I can set the Z order so that it will always show when it is in the smaller size version. (i.e - if a powerpoint slide is running (via F5) it would take up the whole screen but with my small countdown timer I want it to have the 0 z order so that it will still display and then run as a countdown to the powerpoint (note this is just one example of why I want it to always show in the smaller version.

I have hooked into the Size Change Event and then used the following:

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
.....
```

to do a number of things (i.e. change background image if in Maximised mode.  In the else side of this I would then like to set the z order property if possible.

Does anyone know of the code that would help me acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Form.TopMost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx).

> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost)
>   forms even if it is not the active or foreground form. Topmost forms
>   are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the
>   windows on the desktop.

Usage:

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) {
    TopMost = true;
}
else {
    TopMost = false;
}
```

or

```
TopMost = (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized);
```

Comment: Hi @kenny - can you look at my reply to Hans below.  The property you have mentioned does not behave exactly as i was expecting - can you shed any further light/help on this?  Cheers